# Where does the expression of the unit vector $\hat{z}$ in terms of unit vectors in spherical coordinates comes from?

Tags: coordinate-systems

You can find everywhere that:
$$\hat{z}=cos(\theta)\hat{r}-sen(\theta)\hat{\theta}$$ but if i am not mistaken you cand find this kind of relations using derivates in this way: $$\hat{z}=\frac{\partial r}{\partial z}\hat{r} + \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}\hat{\theta} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}\hat{\phi}$$
I got this expression from the tensorial definition of basis vectors.
My question is how is the $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}=-sen(\theta)$ if $z=rcos(\theta)$ and deriving in an implicit way respecto to z I got this:
$$\frac{d z}{d z} = \frac{d r}{d z}cos(\theta)-rsen(\theta)\frac{d \theta}{d z}$$
Using the fact that $\frac{d r}{d z} = cos(\theta)$ and $ \frac{d z}{d z} =\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta)$ we get: $$\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta)=\cos^2(\theta)-rsen(\theta)\frac{d \theta}{d z}$$
And then:
$$\frac{d \theta}{d z}=\frac{-sen(\theta)}{r}$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuitive methods for representation of Cartesian Coordinates in terms of Spherical Coordinates as basis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/503161/). See the accepted answer there.

Comment: It helps but i would like to use derivates to deduce these instead of geometry.

Comment: $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}=-\sin\theta$ is dimensionally inconsistent and therefore incorrect. In fact, your second equation is also dimensionally incorrect.

Comment: I also see that this definition does not give a unitary vector, how can I fix that?

Comment: What is true is $\hat{z} = \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial z}$, and so I'm not sure where your second expression comes from (I mean, it's definitely incorrect because it's dimensionally inconsistent, i.e., the units don't match in the different terms).

Comment: Where does that expression comes from? the one that you wrote there?

Answer (score 0):

### Transforming the derivative of a test function

Consider the derivative of a test function $f$
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial r}{\partial z} \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}
$$
First we'll evaluate the $z$ derivatives using the expressions
\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& r \sin\theta \cos\phi \\
y &=& r \sin\theta \sin\phi \\
z &=& r \cos\theta
\end{eqnarray}
yielding$^\dagger$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial z} &=& \frac{z}{r} = \cos\theta \\
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z} &=& -\frac{\sin \theta}{r} \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
Then
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \left(\cos \theta \frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin\theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right)f
$$

### Interpretation as vector transformation

Now, in differential geometry terms, we can identify $\partial_z$, $\partial_r$, and $\partial_\theta$ as vectors adapted to the coordinates $z, r, \theta$. **These are not unit vectors**. However, in terms of this (non-normalized) basis, we can identify the vector with components $\langle 0, 0, 1 \rangle$ in the $x,y,z$ basis as having components $\langle \cos\theta, -\frac{\sin\theta}{r}, 0\rangle$ in the $r, \theta, \phi$ basis.

In differential geometry language, what we have done is express the vector
$$
z^\mu \partial_\mu 
$$
in two different coordinate systems. We found that
\begin{eqnarray}
z^r &=& \cos\theta \\
z^\theta &=& -\frac{\sin\theta}{r} \\
z^\phi &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}

Even though our basis vectors are not unit vectors, we expect that the vector $z^\mu$ still must be a unit vector since the norm of the vector shouldn't change under a coordinate system. To check this, note that the metric in spherical coordinates is
$$
ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu = dr^2 + r^2 d\theta^2 + r^2 \sin^2 \theta d\phi^2
$$
Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
g_{\mu\nu} z^\mu z^\nu &=& g_{rr} z^r z^r + g_{\theta\theta} z^\theta z^\theta \\
&=& \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2\theta \\
&=& 1
\end{eqnarray}

### Using an orthonormal basis

On the other hand, we can explicitly check that the vector $v^\mu \partial_\mu = \partial_\theta$ is not a unit vector, since
$$
g_{\mu\nu} v^\mu v^\nu = g_{\theta\theta} = r^2
$$
So the *normalized* basis vector in the $\theta$ direction is actually
$$
\hat{e}_\theta = \frac{1}{r} \partial_\theta
$$
Just for completeness, we note that
$$
\hat{e}_r = \partial_r
$$
and
$$
\hat{e}_\theta = \frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\partial_\phi
$$
We can re-express the components of $z^\mu$ in terms of this orthormal basis as
$$
z^\mu \partial_\mu = \cos\theta \hat{e}_r - \sin\theta \hat{e}_\theta 
$$
Then it is more obvious that the norm is 1. This is also the result you wanted.

---

### $^\dagger$ Appendix: Calculating $\frac{\partial r}{\partial z}$, $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}$

Rereading your question, I think you're particularly interested in calculating the $z$ derivatives.

First, let's start with our defining equations for spherical coordinates, but define $\rho^2 = x^2+y^2$ and re-express them as
\begin{eqnarray}
\rho &=& r \sin\theta \\
z &=& r\cos\theta
\end{eqnarray}
Now we differentiate both equations with respect to $z$. Of course, since $\rho$ only depends on $x$ and $y$, we have that $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z} = 0$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
0 &=&  \sin \theta \frac{\partial r}{\partial z} + r \cos\theta \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}  \\
1 &=& \cos\theta\frac{\partial r}{\partial z}  - r \sin\theta \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}
\end{eqnarray}
Solving this system of equations for $\frac{\partial r}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}$ yields the claimed result (eg, see [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve+%7B0+%3D+sin%28t%29+x+%2B+r+cos%28t%29+y%2C+1+%3D+cos%28t%29+x+-+r+sin%28t%29+y%7D+for+x%2C+y)).